# The JUnit Assume.assumeNotNull throws nullpointer instead of skipping test

Tags: groovy, junit

I have this junit (using JUnit 4.12) test in groovy that should only be executed if **getenv != null**:

```
    import org.junit.Assume
    import org.junit.Before
    import org.junit.Ignore
    import org.junit.Test
    ...
    @Test
    public void skipWhenNull() throws Exception {
        def getenv = System.getenv("bogos")
        if( getenv == null) {
            println "Its null!"
        }
        Assume.assumeNotNull(getenv);
        println "Test executing!"
    }
```

But when I run the test it prints: `Its null!` and then throws a NullPointer exception (in the line: `Assume.assumeNotNull(getenv);` ). Is the point of: `Assume.assumeNotNull(expr)` not that it will skip the test when `expr` evaluates to null instead of throwing a Nullpointer?

Comment: It is supposed to halt and ignore the test when `assumeNotNull` gets a `null` value. You might double-check your imports, maybe you are getting some other library with the same class/method. Assuming you are getting the "It's null" printed out... is that correct?

Comment: Also, is the NPE being thrown from the assert line?

Comment: Yes see my updated post

Comment: What version of JUnit are you using?

Comment: I am using version 4.12

Answer (score 2):

I thought this might be a bug, but I think this is rather a consequence of Groovy's dynamic type system in its default behavior. `Assume.assumeNotNull(Object... objects)` method uses varargs parameters. It means that in case of passing a non-array element compiler wraps it within an array of expected type.

```java
String getenv = System.getenv("bogos"); 

Assume.assumeNotNull(getenv); // --> Assume.assumeNotNull(new Object[] { getenv });
```

This is what Java's static compiler does. So in case of `getenv == null` we end up with:

```java
Assume.assumeNotNull(new Object[] { null });
```

A non-empty array that contains a single null element. On the other hand, if we specify a variable with an array type and we assign a `null` value to it, calling the same method will cause `NullPointerException`, just like in the following example:

```java
String[] array = null;

Assume.assumeNotNull(array); // --> throws NPE
```

This is at least what happens in Java. Now, why it fails in Groovy unit test? Groovy is a dynamically typed language by default, so it behaves quite differently in this area. It seems like Groovy's type system applies `null` value to the method type without wrapping it within an array, so in case of passing a `null` to a method that expects e.g. `Object... objects` we always get `objects == null` instead of `objects == new Object[] { null }`.

I started questioning myself if this is a bug or not. From one perspective I would expect dynamic Groovy to behave in the same way that statically compiled code behaves. But on the other hand in a dynamically typed system, this distinction is acceptable (and maybe even desirable), because dynamic type system infers the type at the runtime. It sees `null` so it thinks that we intend to assign `null` value to a variable of type `Object[]`.

### Solution

There are two ways you can solve this problem.

#### 1. Enable static compilation

If you don't use Groovy's dynamic and metaprogramming features in your test case you can easily annotate it with `@groovy.transform.CompileStatic` annotation to generate a bytecode that is more similar to Java's bytecode. For instance, this is what the bytecode of your method in the dynamic Groovy looks like:

```
@Test
public void skipWhenNull() throws Exception {
    CallSite[] var1 = $getCallSiteArray();
    Object getenv = var1[4].call(System.class, "bogos");
    if (ScriptBytecodeAdapter.compareEqual(getenv, (Object)null)) {
        var1[5].callCurrent(this, "Its null!");
    }

    var1[6].call(Assume.class, getenv);
    var1[7].callCurrent(this, "Test executing!");
}
```

And here is the same method but annotated with `@CompileStatic` from the bytecode perspective:

```
@Test
public void skipWhenNull() throws Exception {
    String getenv = System.getenv("bogos");
    Object var10000;
    if (getenv == null) {
        DefaultGroovyMethods.println(this, "Its null!");
        var10000 = null;
    }

    Assume.assumeNotNull(new Object[]{getenv});
    var10000 = null;
    DefaultGroovyMethods.println(this, "Test executing!");
    var10000 = null;
}
```

#### 2. Wrap `getenv` with an array

Alternatively, you can make more explicit call to `Assume.assumeNotNull` method. If you replace:

```
Assume.assumeNotNull(getenv);
```

with:

```
Assume.assumeNotNull([getenv] as Object[]);
```

then you will wrap parameter explicitly with `Object[]` array and you will prevent from passing an array object that is represented by `null`, but a single element array holding `null` value instead.